# Encountered Jsp validation issue in Struts 2

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl

In a JSP page, Am using Struts 2 `<s:select>` option and listed the values as mentioned in the below code.

```
<s:select label="Select your month" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
cssClass="form-control" {'opt1':'January','opt2':'February'}" name="cb.month" />
```

Am getting the form validation issue as

```
Encountered ":" at line 1, column 48.
Was expecting one of:"}" ..."}" ..."." ..."[" ...";" ...">" ..."gt" ..."<" ...
"lt" ...">=" ..."ge" ..."<=" ..."le" ..."==" ..."eq" ..."!=" ..."ne" ..."&&"...
"and" ..."||" ..."or" ..."*" ..."+" ....
```

Kindly help me on how to resolve it.

**Updated Image**

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: You are missing some attributes.

Comment: @AleksandrM May i know what kind of attributes am missing here?

Comment: The one which is required for this tag.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<s:select label="Select your month" headerKey="-1" headerValue="Select Month"
cssClass="form-control" list="#{'opt1':'January','opt2':'February'}" name="cb.month" />
```

[`s:select`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/select.html) tag has a list attribute that is necessary to this tag. Also use a correct OGNL syntax to instantiate a `Map`.

Comment: Added with the `list`, still same issue exists.

Comment: Are you sure? still same issue exists?

Comment: Yes, I even placed the above code in my JSP page. See Updated Screenshot

Comment: My NetBeans 8.0 IDE, shows the `list` value as form validation issue as mentioned in question. (See the image,`list` value in RED)

Comment: @Sabarish You had errors because you have missed *required* attribute of the `s:select` tag, and jsp syntax errors. Your IDE incorrectly validates a valid OGNL expression. And this is another issue. Forget about RED, run app and see how it works.